# Параметр из ссылки в инпут

Tags: forms, php, javascript

[Пример формы](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/), как из ссылки, по которой форма вызывается, поставить параметр для заполнения конкретного инпута?

Comment: по всей видимости речь о `.focus()`

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос у вас странный.
Если касается php то:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['параметр']?>" />
```

Если касается js то в jquery есть :

```
var param = jQuery(document).getUrlParam("параметр");
ну и jQuery('input#idинпута').val(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('Ainp')[0].onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('inp')[0].value = 'Данные для инпута';
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="Ainp">~ Ввести данные в инпут ~</a>
<br><br>

<input type="text" class="inp">
```